# alertdialog list database to webview html field via javascript android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

on webview I have a button when user click on it javascript call a AlertDialog who has a database list values.. when user click on a value to put from list to html text field application crash... :( if I add on database only numbers and click on list not crash but not put on html form... any hep about this please? Sorry for my bad English... Isn't full code, I think on click is the problem...

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showCustomUsersPopup(){
    context.popupDialog.showCustomUsersPopup();
}
```

//

```
public void showCustomRegionPopup() {
listRegion.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String region =(String) listRegion.getItemAtPosition(position);
            SQLiteDatabase database = context.pdfDatabaseManager.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * From " + PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_REGION_TABLE + " WHERE "+ PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_REGION +"="+region+";", null);}
```

Comment: try replacing this `="+region+";"` to this `='"+region+"'"`

Comment: @L2_Paver now the application not crash when I choose numbers or letters on the list but list can't put values to webview html form now... We have solution about this?

Comment: I cant see the problem based on the amount of your post above, maybe you can make another question and post the necessary code

Comment: @L2_Paver you have right friend, thank you for your answer there you help me. :)